# comparing the default enabled modules of httpd on CentOS to apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, httpd, migration, apache2

I'm migrating a server from Ubuntu 16.04 running Apache2 to CentOS 7.5 using httpd.

By checking the enabled modules on both machines I found that httpd enables many more modules by default in comparison to apache2 on the Ubuntu machine.

Is there any there any specific reason for this, or can I simply disable the modules in the

- `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/` on the **CentOS** machine which are not listed in the
- `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` on my old **Ubuntu** machine?

My motivation is to *disable* all potential security issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though [this post about increasing security and performance with disabling all unneeded modules](https://serverfault.com/questions/348829/on-centos-5-7-using-apache2-should-i-disable-the-list-of-default-modules-that-ar) is quite old, I followed the recommendation of user [Khaled](https://serverfault.com/users/58024/khaled) and disabled all modules I do no longer need in my current configuration. I checked through the activated modules on the Ubuntu machine and read about the modules purpose in the [official apache module docu](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/).

Of course each setup is individual and everyone should check which packages he/she needs in their individual configuration. Still I'm posting my final configuration as feedback to my question. Maybe someone find it useful:

The content of the file `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf` on my CentOS 7.5 machine:

```
#
# This file loads most of the modules included with the Apache HTTP
# Server itself.
#

LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
#LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
#LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule dialup_module modules/mod_dialup.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
#LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
```